# Libgdx and Bluetooth on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, libgdx

I have been trying for months on getting my poker game Bluetooth functionality to work but I am beginning to suspect that I might have a wrong understanding of how Bluetooth data exchange actually works, hope someone here could point me to the right direction.

Firstly I have successfully created the scanning and connecting part as shown (Both device are connected):

[image]

Once I hit the "Start Game" button on one of the device, the game start on that device but on the other device, it doesn't start the game. Instead it merely add the string "start" to my list, acting as if it is a player.

[image]

The following is my LibGDX bluetoothscreen code (I will keep it short for easy reading):

```
public class BluetoothScreen extends GameScreen {

public BluetoothScreen(Poker game) {
    super(game);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();

    startBtn.addListener( new DefaultActorListener() {
        @Override
        public void touchUp( InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button ) {
            // Send a "start" message to Android and allow Android send the message to all other connected bluetooth device.
            Poker.actionResolver.sendMsg("start");
        }
    });
}

public void startGame() {
    stage.getRoot().removeActor(btnTable);
    stage.getRoot().removeActor(scrollTable);
    createGame();
    gameStart = true;
}

@Override
public void read(final String s) {
    if( s.equals("start") ) {
        startGame();
    }
    else {
        if( this.players.size < 5 ) {
            // Add player to the list
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

This part of the code above doesn't seems to work, what am I doing wrong?. if( s.equals("start") ) { startGame(); }

Apologise if I did not explained this well. Every little tiny help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Likely your issues is that your .equals("start") test is failing for some reason (extra characters, character set differences, whatever) causing a fallthrough to the add-a-player code which you failed to post.  But the real problem is that rather than asking a question with detail to be reasonably answerable, you just waited and slapped a bounty on the insufficient originally posting.  Try adding some logging of what exactly the argument to that comparison is.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have mentioned that .equals("start") works on the device which I've clicked on the Start Game button but on the other, it doesn't starts the game. I have also provided the screenshots that shows a player with the "start" name, so extra characters are not possible. As for logging,  its difficult to log any issues on Bluetooth since I can only connect one cable to one device at a time. Not sure if you understand this but just hope someone with Bluetooth experience could help by pointing me to the right directions.

Comment: Log on the device which displayed the erroneous "start" player on screen.  You need to understand why exactly that comparison is failing.  Don't assume that just because you don't see extra characters on the screen they are not there.  Run down exactly what is in those string objects.  Make sure you aren't getting two messages and confusing things by processing both.  You can solve this by logging, but you'll need to be crafty in setting traps to catch various possible errors in the act of sabotaging your program.

Comment: For the record though, you can run logcat on two Android devices at the same time from the same host, if you use a distinct command line window for each and explicitly specify the target device to adb.  If it were me, I'd tee each to a file while live grepping for interesting messages.  You can probably also do it with some of the IDEs.